# Reference for beginners: psychology

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a book that is not too rigorous but provides a good introduction to psychology as a preparation for a university-level course. Any suggestions? It is an introductory course.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at former lecture notes and look up the references (especially books as they mostly provide a broader view of a topic)?

Comment: I found some archives, but these have a lot of gaps and reading on websites just confused me even more.

Comment: I would recommend to look in your local (university) library. Either you can try to look for yourself and just "browse the bookshelves" or you ask the staff. The majority of library employees are professionally trained to help you find appropriate literature.

Comment: Ah yes :) Will investigate this further:)

Comment: Unfortunetly I have had to close this question because shopping type questions aren't on topic for us here on Stack Exchange. If you'd like further recommendations, consider [joining us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2250/the-axon-terminal) where book questions like this are permitted, even encouraged: [we have a whole room for them](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6314/cogsci-reading-room)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making Up The Mind by Chris Frith is fantastic for a casual introduction to general Psychology concepts. ( [http://www.amazon.com/Making-Mind-Brain-Creates-Mental/dp/1405160225/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1386952875&sr=8-1&keywords=Making+Up+The+Mind](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1405160225) )

I would also recommend Bonk! by Mary Roach if you're looking for an easy read to ease you into the topic of Human Sexuality within Psychology. ( [http://www.amazon.com/Bonk-The-Curious-Coupling-Science/dp/0393334791/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1386952898&sr=8-1&keywords=bonk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393334791)! )

Both of these books are informative and educational, and present what would otherwise be extremely dry research as entertaining prose.

Also, I would highly recommend going to http://www.ted.com and watching any of the talks by Vs. Ramachandran - Ramachandran is extremely talented in explaining Psychological concepts in a down-to-earth manner.

Comment: No problem, proper credit goes to my Intro Psych/Human Sexuality prof., both were required texts for those respective classes, and I recommend them because they actually helped me learn things!

Comment: I found the book by Mary Roach :) Looking forward to reading it :)

Comment: It's an absolutely hilarious and educational read. She also has some TED talks about Sexuality topics, and they're equally hilarious. I would definitely recommend the Frith book if you can find it, though, as prep for your intro course (it deals with general Psychology, whereas Roach is specific to sexuality).

Comment: I found the Frith book last night :) And have already started on Roach. It is hilarious! :)