# What can I study as a layman to develop practical knowledge of human psychology

Tags: social-psychology, learning, psychology

What can I study as a layman to learn enough facets of psychology to develop better understanding of human behaviour? Unfortunately as I know nothing of the field I'm not really certain about what I should even look for. Any suggestions such as subjects, books, documentaries and even advice would be appreciated.

I am interested in topics such as personal fears, prejudices, motivations, mental health illnesses, hostilities, etc. On a larger scale I want a better understanding of social issues such as resistance to change, radicalisation, extremism, value systems, group dynamics, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to CogSci. This question is really broad and apparently *any* introductory book on behavior seems to meet your needs.

Comment: Hello. Yes, I'm really not sure of where to begin (or even what to ask). I'm not interested so much in the history of the field, clinical applications, physical processes or broad meta-concepts but rather practical knowledge for use in life.

Comment: You can check out answers to a couple of other similar questions on this forum (both closed of course): https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5131/reference-for-beginners-psychology, https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/best-book-for-cognitive-science

Comment: Thinking fast and slow by Kahneman may also be interesting

Comment: Thanks for the responses and references. I understand this question is too broad for specific conversation.